# pgfkeys: Forward params to other command

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In the following MWE I would like to forward a list of key-value-pairs to the `\node` command. I tried to store the list in `\nodeparam`, but this seems to not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
    /absolutenode/.is family, /absolutenode,
    default/.style = {},
    node/.store in = \nodeparam,
}

\newcommand\absolutenode[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/absolutenode, default, #1}%
    \tikz[]{%
        \node[\nodeparams] {#2};
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \absolutenode[node={draw=black, fill=green}]{Test}
\end{document}
```

How can I "forward" the list `{draw=black, fill=green}` to `\node[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you are looking for but at least this allows you to do what you want, and hopefully allows others to understand your question better. (I do not understand the full picture, i.e. I am struggling to see what that should be ultimately be good for.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
    /absolutenode/.is family, /absolutenode/.cd,
    default/.style = {},
    node/.code=\tikzset{mynodestyle/.style={#1}},
}

\newcommand\absolutenode[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/absolutenode, default, #1}%
    \tikz[]{%
        \node[mynodestyle] {#2};
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \absolutenode[node={draw=black, fill=green}]{Test}
\end{document}
```